# Error query toggle open all div when click a item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code

On Html:

```
<div id="item-1-desc">ABC</div>
<div id="item-2-desc">DEF</div>
<div id="item-3-desc">XYZ</div>
```

And jquery:

```
    $('div[id^=item-][id$=-desc]').hide().before('<a href="#" class="see-more" id="toggle-desc">More</a>');

    $('a#toggle-desc').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('see-more');
        if($this.hasClass('see-more')){
            $this.text('More');         
        } else {
            $this.text('Close');
        }
        $('div[id^=item-][id$=-desc]').slideToggle(200);
    });
```

When I click on more, it open all div(http://jsfiddle.net/3v25guz6). How to click only show a item desc ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to target only the `div` which is next sibling of the clicked `a` so

```
$(this).next('div').slideToggle(200);
```

Also, id of an element must be unique, so for the dynamically added elements use the class to register the click handler

```js
$('div[id^=item-][id$=-desc]').hide().before('<a href="#" class="see-more">More</a>');

$('.see-more').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass('see-more');
  $this.text($this.hasClass('see-more') ? 'More' : 'Close');
  $(this).next('div[id^=item-][id$=-desc]').slideToggle(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item-1-desc">ABC</div>
<div id="item-2-desc">DEF</div>
<div id="item-3-desc">XYZ</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3v25guz6/2/

```
$('div[id^=item-][id$=-desc]').hide().before('<a href="#" class="see-more" id="toggle-desc">More</a>');

 $('a#toggle-desc').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.toggleClass('see-more');
     if ($this.hasClass('see-more')) {
         $this.text('More');
     } else {
         $this.text('Close');
     }
     $this.next().slideToggle(200);
 });
```